# Print a colored string (Assembly 8086)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

How is it possible to make a string colored in assembly 8086?

Comment: Int 10h/ah=9 doesn't set the cursor. It prints a character in a specified color. Even if you had set the cursor - 0,0 is upper left (not right)

Comment: So should I do ah=9 and int 10h before and then set the cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the interrupt functions wrong:

[`INT 10h, AH=09h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0099.htm) prints several, same characters at a time. The count is passed in the `CX` register. To print a string, you have to call it as often as characters are in the string, with the other parameters set. The character has to be passed in the `AL` register and the attribute/color has to be passed in the `BL` register. `BH` should (probably) stay `0` and `CX` should stay `1`. `DL` and `DH` are not used by this function, hence you can remove the respective commands.

The initial cursor position can be set with the function [`INT 10h, AH=02h`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0087.htm). Make sure that the `BH` value matches the one in the above code(`0`).

So your code could look like this:

```
  ; ...
  ; Print character of message
  ; Make sure that your data segment DS is properly set
  MOV SI, offset Msg
  mov DI, 0      ; Initial column position 
lop:
  ; Set cursor position
  MOV AH, 02h
  MOV BH, 00h    ; Set page number
  MOV DX, DI     ; COLUMN number in low BYTE
  MOV DH, 0      ; ROW number in high BYTE
  INT 10h
  LODSB          ; load current character from DS:SI to AL and increment SI
  CMP AL, '$'    ; Is string-end reached?
  JE  fin        ; If yes, continue
  ; Print current char
  MOV AH,09H
  MOV BH, 0      ; Set page number
  MOV BL, 4      ; Color (RED)
  MOV CX, 1      ; Character count
  INT 10h
  INC DI         ; Increase column position
  jmp lop
fin:
  ; ...
```

The DOS function `INT 21h` which prints a string till the end-char `$` does not care about the attribute passed to the BIOS function `INT 10h`, so the color is ignored by it and you can remove the corresponding code from `;print the string` to `INT 21h`.

Comment: This only prints the lastest char of the string to me

Comment: I updated the code. Now the cursor position is set for each character.

Comment: Isn't there a way printing the whole string instead making a loop prints one char per loop?

Comment: Not with the BIOS. Look [here](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-10.htm) - there is no such function available. But the preferred (and tremendously faster) way of doing this is circumventing the BIOS and writing to the text-mode screen buffer at 0B800:0h directly. In the screen buffer, a char consists of two bytes: one for the char value and the other for its attribute. But this has to be done in a loop, too. **Hint:** Use `DS:SI` for the source string and `ES:DI` for the screen buffer. Then you can take advantage of the string instructions `LODSB` and `STOSW`.

Comment: @zx485 BIOS offers us [video function 13h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0210.htm) to print a whole colored string.

Comment: @SepRoland: Thanks for pointing that out. I've always preferred the other approach I mentioned.

Comment: @zx485 I must admit I never use it myself. I've always written my own loops instead. Moreover this function is not particularly fast since it just calls upon all the other video BIOS functions that it needs.

Answer (score 3):

Why your current program didn't work was already explained in the answer by zx485. As per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778271/print-a-colored-string#comment98228747_55778385) you can indeed print the whole colored string in one go. BIOS offers us [video function 13h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0210.htm). The full pointer to the text is expected in `ES:BP`, so make sure that the `ES` segment register is setup properly.

```
score db '12345'

...

PROC PrintScore
    pusha
    mov     bp, offset score ; ES:BP points at text
    mov     dx, 0000h        ; DH=Row 0, DL=Column 0
    mov     cx, 5            ; Length of the text
    mov     bx, 0004h        ; BH=Display page 0, BL=Attribute RedOnBlack
    mov     ax, 1300h        ; AH=Function number 13h, AL=WriteMode 0
    int     10h        
    popa
    ret
ENDP PrintScore
```